# LINQ query to combine 2 resultsets

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# LINQ query that has a main query and then 2 other queries depending on if a variable is not set 0.

The query is working, but I need to combine the resultsets and return that.

I want the final resultset to contain the results of the two subqueries combined. Kind of like in a SQL query where you have:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column1 = 'abc' OR column2 = 'xyz'
```

Right now, I think it's using an AND instead of an OR

```
var GeoLocations = rows.Select(r => new ElementSearchGeoLocation(r))
    .Where(t => (t.GeoLocationType == "State" && t.CanViewState(t.GeoLocationState, user)) ||
                (t.GeoLocationType == "City" && t.CanViewCity(t.GeoLocationCity, user)));

if(SystemList != 0)
{
    GeoLocations = GeoLocations.Where(t => (dto.SystemList.Contains(t.SystemID)));
}

if (groupList != 0)
{
    GeoLocations = GeoLocations.Where(t => (dto.groupList.Contains(t.PoliticalID)));
}

return Ok(GeoLocations);
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation of a `PredicateBuilder` that is able to `Or` together two different expressions:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

It's dependant on the following code to be able to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
internal static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
        Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
    {
        return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
    }
}
```

Using this you can now write:

```
var GeoLocations = rows.Select(r => new ElementSearchGeoLocation(r))
    .Where(t => (t.GeoLocationType == "State" && t.CanViewState(t.GeoLocationState, user)) ||
                (t.GeoLocationType == "City" && t.CanViewCity(t.GeoLocationCity, user)));

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False();

if(SystemList != 0)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(t => dto.SystemList.Contains(t.SystemID));
}

if (groupList != 0)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(t => dto.groupList.Contains(t.PoliticalID));
}

return Ok(GeoLocations.Where(predicate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come up for this behaviour

- [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which combines two result sets while culling for duplicates
- [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which simply slams two result sets together

Which one you choose depends on desired behaviour. Note that either of these may or may not work if your queries are actually `IQueryable`s and running from a database (via linq-to-sql or Entity Framework or the like).

As has been mentioned, do not forget that `LINQ` results are lazily-evaluated, and this parts of a query can be safely saved and rehashed for later.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Concat` to add in the additional rows. To make the code super minimal, I would store off the initial `Select first:

```
var AllLocations = rows.Select(r => new ElementSearchGeoLocation(r));
var mainQuery = AllLocations.Where(t => (t.GeoLocationType == "State" && t.CanViewState(t.GeoLocationState, user)) ||
                        (t.GeoLocationType == "City" && t.CanViewCity(t.GeoLocationCity, user)));
```

Then:

```
IEnumerable<GeoLocation> subQuery;
if (SystemList != 0)
   subQuery = AllLocations.Where(...);
else
   subQuery = AllLocations.Where(...);

var GeoLocations = mainQuery.Concat(subQuery);
```

If you care about duplicates, you can use `Union` instead of `Concat` for the last step.

Comment: I fail to see how this is allowing him to OR together an unknown number of different predicates.

Comment: @Servy You could create any number of sub-query objects and `Concat`/`Union` them together at the end. I wasn't addressing the general case though, just showing a correct version of the OPs code